# How to select the first visible jquery tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have a jQuery tab set up and I currently have the ability to hide tabs using

```
$("[href='"+ tabRef +"']").closest("li").hide();
```

I then put the tabRef into an array and pull it out if I need to display that tab again

```
$("[href='"+ tabRef +"']").closest("li").show();
```

What I need to do is to set the first visible tab active. If I use

```
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 0);
```

It will set the first tab active even if it is not visible.  What do I need to do to set the first tab visible?  Loop the tabs and check the properties? or is there something I can add to the active code that will not make hidden tabs active?

Comment: Have you played with pseudo-selectors? https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ talks about one that may apply. Change your $("#tabs") to $("#tabs:visible") and see if that helps.

Comment: That didn't seem to help

Comment: Do you have an example fiddle or something set up that you're using for testing?

Comment: no- sorry I don't

Comment: until a better solution comes along I did what I consider a hack.  When I delete a tab I remove it tab index from an array and then do    $("#contribution_tabs:visible").tabs("option", "active", array[0]);  Not the prettiest code but it seems to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mktgnp3e/91/)**.

You could select the index of the first visible tab using :

```
var first_visible_tab_index = $( "li" ).index($("li:visible:eq(0)"));
```

Then active the tab using the returned inde :

```
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active",  first_visible_tab_index );
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#tabs").tabs();

$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", $( "li" ).index( $("li:visible:eq(0)") ));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li style='display:none'><a href="#tabs-0">Tab 0</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-0" style='display:none'>
    <p>Content for Tab 0</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Content for Tab 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Content for Tab 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="tabid"></div>
```